# Hi! I want to remove all the divs inside the container in one go. How can I do that without any class or id of the inside divs?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, removechild, parent-node

I have created a form to search for things and added them as div in the container. Now for every new search I want all the divs from the container to be removed. How do I do that?

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const form = document.querySelector('#search-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', async function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  clear();
  const searchTerm = form.elements.query.value;

  const config = {
    params: {
      q: searchTerm
    }
  }
  const res = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows`, config);
  displayShows(res.data);

  form.elements.query.value = '';
})

function clear() {
  for (div in container) {
    div.remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="search-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="TV Show Title" name="query">
  <button id="search-btn">Search</button>
</form>

<div class="container">
  <div>Here is div-01</div>
  <div>Here is div-02</div>
  <div>Here is div-03</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all the divs in the container (assuming that you are generating each of them again upon running displayShows()):

In place of clear(), do this:

```
container.innerHTML = ''
```

This will remove everything inside the container div, including the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your divs using something like this below

```
  var e = document.getElementById("you_might_want_a_unique_id");
  var divs = e.querySelectorAll("div");
  for(var i=0;i < divs.length;i ++)
    e.removeChild(divs[i]);
```

Just add an id attribute to your container (incase your have multiple containers)

```
<div id="you_might_want_a_unique_id" class="container">
```